# Style chargify "cfy-container--inline" container

Tags: html, css, chargify

I'm struggling with styling of Chargify container using chargify.js. Though I disabled borders for all fields and for the iframe, I still get the border for the fields container:

[image]

[image]

I wonder if it is possible somehow to remove this border using chargify.js settings. Because everything is rendered in an iframe, so I cannot apply local CSS overrides.

Documentation does not tell anything about styles of this container.